# Matlab function reshape doesnt´t calculate the last dimension while trying to create a 3D image from .raw binary image file

Tags: matlab, reshape

I created binarized images by using the Otsu methode in Matlab and cut out parts of the resulting image using a function. Now i want to take a look at these images with the VolumeViewer command. I know the x,y and z dimensions of the resulting imgages. I currently run this code doing it(excluding the volumeViewerwhich happens after the loop):

```
    files= {'C3\C3_000mal_550_539_527.raw';...
           
            };
 for i=1:numel(files)
         Image = fopen(files{i},'r');
    ImageData{i} = fread(Image,Inf,'uint16=>uint16');
    ImageData{i} = reshape(ImageData{i},550,539,[]);
    fclose(openedCrystalImage);
    end
```

Using this code runs into the following error using reshape:

> Error using reshape
> Product of known dimensions, 296450, not divisible into total number of elements, 78114575.

I did the maths and 550*539=296450 and  296450 * 527=156229150: If we divide the last number by the number of elements it equals 2 and thus is divisible into the total number of elements. In my opinion the reshape function is not able to find the size of the last dimension or defines it as 1.
Defining the size of z also results in an error suggesting using the brackets [], so the function can find it.

> Error using reshape
> Number of elements must not change. Use [] as one of the size inputs to automatically calculate the appropriate size
> for that dimension.

Now to the weird part. This code works for another set of images, with diffrent sizes of the x,y and z ranges. So don´t know where the issue lies to be frank. So i would really appreciate and Answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The error lies here:

```
ImageData{i} = fread(Image,Inf,'uint16=>uint16');
```

Apparently by saving them as .raw before it converts the image to an 8 bit file rather than 16 bits it had before. Therefore, my dimension is double the size of the number of elements. With this alteration it works:

```
ImageData{i} = fread(Image,Inf,'uint8=>uint8');
```

The reason i was able to look at the other pictures was that the z range was divisble by 2.

So the reshape function was not the problem but size of the integer data while creating the array for the variable ImageData.

P.S. I just started out programming so the accuracy in the answer should be taken with a grain of salt

Comment: .raw files are that, raw data. So you may have saved them as uint8, but to clarify, this is not a requirement. raw data can be anything, you just need to know what it is to read it.